# Cant display data from array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with the print out Data from the array.

I have

```
    {{orders}} =    
  [{"item":"DELL","quantity":6,"price":144},
  {"item":"Samsung","quantity":3,"price":3131},
  {"item":"222222","quantity":1,"price":31},
  {"item":"111111111","quantity":1,"price":13}]
```

I try in View

```
  <div ng-repeat="order in orders track by $index">
    <span>{{ order[$index].item }}
    </span>
  </div>
```

And nothing. Can someone help me with that??

Edit:
Still does not work

{{orders}}

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders track by $index">
<span>
  {{order.item}}
</span>
```

and nothing

controller:

```
$scope.ListOfOrders = function () {
        return ApiService.cart.list().then(function (resp) {
            $scope.orders = resp[0].order;
            console.log(resp[0].order)
        });
}
```

Comment: order is the item in array, so  ` {{order.item}}`  or ` {{orders[$index].item}}`  to display that item.

Comment: Study some tutorials

Answer (score 3):

**UI**

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders track by $index">
<span>{{order.item}}</span>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.orders = [{
    "item": "DELL",
    "quantity": 6,
    "price": 144
  }, {
    "item": "Samsung",
    "quantity": 3,
    "price": 3131
  }, {
    "item": "222222",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 31
  }, {
    "item": "111111111",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 13
  }]
```

Working **[Solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/EcSdYTqLCrRtkdh0sgNw?p=preview)**

Comment: I make EDit POST can u look again, what co be wrong??

Comment: What is printing in console for `resp[0].order`?

Comment: [{"item":"DELL","quantity":6,"price":144},{"item":"ziemniaki","quantity":3,"price":3131},{"item":"Wisnie","quantity":1,"price":31},{"item":"111111111","quantity":1,"price":13}]

Comment: And where are you calling your `ListOfOrders`  function?

Comment: typeof this console.log was string, now is all working i make JSON.parse

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bind `order[$index]`, ng-repeat itself iterates over every object so just write :

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders track by $index">
  <span>{{ order.item }}
  </span>
</div>
```